# OR en input no devuelve el segundo elemento cuando el input es vacío python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
inp_usr = input("Hola, dame un input" or 3)
print(inp_usr)
```

Pero cuando al `input` no le doy nada, simplemente imprime vacío. ¿Por qué?

Comment: La solucion es poner el or afuera del la funcion input. queda

````inp_usr = input("Hola, dame un input" ) or 3
print(inp_usr)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El **or** se evalua con el texto, si lo que pretendes es dar un valor por default colocalo fuera de la funcion:

```py
inp_usr = input("Hola, dame un input") or 3
print(inp_usr)
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias